# Using rows from the first query in the sub-query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a bit complicated query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT l1.item_id, l1.uid, l2.id, l2.uid, u.prename, l1.item_id, l2.item_id,
  (SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      p1.item_id,
      COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM pages_likes AS p1
      JOIN pages_likes AS p2 ON p1.item_id = p2.item_id AND p1.status = p2.status
    WHERE p1.uid = 391 AND p2.uid = 1091
    GROUP BY p1.id
    ORDER BY p1.date DESC
  ) AS t) AS total

FROM pages_likes l1 
  JOIN users u on u.id = l1.uid 
  JOIN pages_likes l2 on l1.item_id = l2.item_id 
  JOIN users_likes ul on l1.uid = ul.uid 
WHERE ul.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
      AND l1.uid != 1091 AND l2.uid = 1091 
      AND (l1.status = 1 AND l2.status = 1) 
      AND u.gender = 2 
GROUP BY l1.uid 
ORDER BY 
  total DESC,
  l1.uid DESC, 
  l1.date DESC
```

What I expect: It should display all users, sorted by *total page likes we have in common* that also are *the most liked users this week*.

The thing is that I inserted values (391 and 1091) as user id to test the query. But since it should be dynamic I'll need to use the row of the first query `l1.uid` in the subquery, so it should be `WHERE p1.uid = l1.uid AND p2.uid = 1091` but mysql can't find the row.

`status = 1`  means user liked this page, `status = 0` means user disliked this page.

Table structure here:

```
CREATE TABLE pages_likes
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uid INT NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    item_id INT,
    status TINYINT
);
CREATE INDEX item_index ON pages_likes (item_id);
CREATE INDEX uid_index ON pages_likes (uid);

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fb_uid VARCHAR(255),
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    pass VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    gender TINYINT NOT NULL,
    birthdate DATE,
    signup DATETIME NOT NULL,
    lang VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255),
    prename VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    projects VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    views INT DEFAULT 0,
    verified DATETIME
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_index ON users (id);
CREATE INDEX uid_index ON users (id);

CREATE TABLE users_likes
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uid INT NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    item_id INT,
    status TINYINT
);
CREATE INDEX item_index ON users_likes (item_id);
CREATE INDEX uid_index ON users_likes (uid);
```

Comment: Can you explain more your goal, with an example if possible. This query will be performed for one user. Agree ? (391 in your example?). Can you be more clear about this _sorted by total page likes we have in common that also are the most liked users this week._

Comment: It *is* complicated. Can you perhaps distill it to just the part you find problematic?

Comment: My main goal right now is to sort by page likes I have in common with users (which is the SELECT subquery-subquery). I use `SUM` in a subquery to see how much rows there are in the next subquery. So it's mainly the subquery-part. I showed my full query, because maybe I could improve the whole query or doesn't even need the subquery? However, I couldn't find another way to get common page likes I have with users. Only with that subquery-subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried different alias names for your subquery and then use alias from outer query? It works for me in this simple example: http://rextester.com/MJOL87502

Sadly I cannot test in your sqlfiddle, since that site often doesn't respond or throws errors (like it does now).

You could also use Window Functions and replace your subselect with something as simple as `SUM(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p1.id, p1.item_id)`, but MySQL does not support Window Functions.

Comment: I think the problem is that I have a subquery in a subquery, because I want to SUM the COUNT of the inner subquery. I edited and added my table structure to my question.